# How do I perform a 3 parameter geotransformation and projection in Sql Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coordinate-system, datum

I have a table with latitude longitude (NAD27) columns in it.  I compute two other columns, X and Y, representing Web Mercator (WGS84) location.

Currently I'm using a Arcmap to do this, by applying the recommended geotransformation for the study area - the [3 parameter (geocentric) geotransformation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Equation-based_methods) - to go from NAD27 to WGS84.

I would like to do this entirely within Sql Server 2012. **From what I can tell, Sql Server does not support datum transformations out of the box.** Does anyone know of a Sql library that supports this geotransformation?  I would like to simply use the same coefficients in Sql that I'm currently using in Arcmap.

I also need to project from WGS84 lat/long into web mercator.  I see [this formula implemented in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957568/125400), but if someone has a Sql stored procedure that does this, it would be great.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no working OO solution at moment for datum transformations. Easiest way to build it in database would be use http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/ lib- Or take existing code and convert it to T-SQL which i tried...

Comment: @simplexio Thanks, any luck with the T-SQL conversion?

Comment: How accurate do you want your converted coordinates to be? Or does accuracy matter all that much?

Comment: @Mintx I'd like to reproduce the same results that I currently getting using Arcmap.

Comment: This is not what databases were designed for.  I suggest you seek other options.

Comment: You could write some simple script (e.g. perl or python (even the ArcPy bindings if available on your Db server) or bash shell and the OGR tools, or Windows Power Shell) to do the reprojection.

Comment: Offcourse. If you can change db to PostGIS, it has re-tranformation support. MS SQL server might be good db and has good support, but i looses to postgresq when we are talking pre made tools

Comment: @Geoist I'd like to treat this as just another math problem.  SQL should have enough math functions to perform this calculation in a stored procedure without involving any specialized GIS software.

Comment: @simplexio I am working with an organization that uses Sql Server as its enterprise database.  I would like to support a GIS workflow (importing 3rd party data in NAD27, and exposing it to the web in web mercator) without requiring new software to be purchased and maintained.

Comment: I think the difficult part is the lat-lon to XYZ and back conversions. The back portion is iterative, I believe. If working in a limited area, try running the 3 parameter and see if you can generate standard lat-lon offsets (or convert to a table and use that + interpolation. Altho at that point, maybe figure out how to access the NADCON files instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the javascript to SQL, this is probably how you would handle that:

```
SELECT  FromX, 
        FromY, 
        CASE WHEN FromX > 180 THEN NULL ELSE FromX * 0.017453292519943295 * 6378137.0 END AS mercatorX_lon2,
        CASE WHEN FromY > 90 THEN NULL ELSE 3189068.5 * LOG((1.0 + SIN(FromY * 0.017453292519943295)) / (1.0 - SIN(FromY * 0.017453292519943295))) END AS mercatorY_lat2
FROM TABLENAME
```

I think the following will answer your first question.  It will require quite a bit of error checking.  To assist, you can find the original equation here:  http://www.colorado.edu/geography/gcraft/notes/datum/gif/molodens.gif

```
--fromTheta :column --radians
--fromLamda :column --radians
--fromH     :column --meters

DECLARE @fromA float = 6378206.4        --radius of earth, meters
DECLARE @fromF float =1.0/294.9786982   --Flattening
DECLARE @toA float =6378137.0           --radius of earth, meters
DECLARE @toF float = 1.0/298.257223563  --Flattening
DECLARE @dA float = @toA - @fromA       --change in equatorial radius
DECLARE @dX float = -8.0                --change in X, meters
DECLARE @dY float = 160.0               --change in Y, meters
DECLARE @dZ float = 176.0               --change in Z, meters
DECLARE @dF float = @toF-@fromF         --change in flattening
DECLARE @fromES float = 2.0*@fromF - @fromF*@fromF --first eccentricity squared
DECLARE @bda float = 1.0-@fromF         --polar radius divided by equatorial radius

--RM = (@fromA*(1-@fromES)/POWER(1-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta), 1.5))

--RN = (@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta)))

SELECT 

((((-@dX*sin(fromTheta)*cos(fromLamda)-@dY*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromLamda))+@dZ*cos(fromTheta))+@dA*(@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta)))*@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*cos(fromTheta)/@fromA)+@df*((@fromA*(1-@fromES)/POWER(1-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta), 1.5))/@bda+(@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta)))*@bda)*sin(fromTheta)*cos(fromTheta))/((@fromA*(1-@fromES)/POWER(1-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta), 1.5)) + fromH) AS deltaTheta,
(-@dX*sin(fromLamda)+@dY*cos(fromLamda))/((((@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta))) +fromH) * cos(fromTheta)) AS deltaLamda,
@dX*cos(fromTheta)*cos(fromLamda)+@dY*cos(fromTheta)*sin(fromLamda)+@dZ*sin(fromTheta)-@da*@fromA/(@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta)))+@dF*@bda*(@fromA/SQRT(1.00-@fromES*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta)))*sin(fromTheta)*sin(fromTheta) AS deltaH

FROM TABLENAME
```

Edit: a couple variables that should have been column names, and a missing comma and parenthesis.

Edit: one more parenthesis.

I've tested this formula and it works using random points against ArcGISs transform.  Remember that your units may be in feet/degrees.  Also remember these results are deltas, so you'll have to add them against your values to obtain your final results.

Comment: Thanks, I think the XYZ deltas need to be applied after converting from lat,long into XYZ space where XY and Z axis origin is at the center of the earth.

Comment: Im going to print that gif, and frame it in the wall in front of my desk.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall This method is the abridged Molodensky, where the deltas you get back are actually in arc-seconds and can be applied to your initial lat/longs to get the translation to your target datum. I don't know your AOI, but geocentric is usually the least accurate (but easiest!) way to get from NAD27->WGS84.

Comment: Also note ike's `@dX @dY @dZ` values which may be different depending on which `NAD_1927_To_WGS_1984` geocentric method you've chosen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to a similar question:

http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/discussions/286893

I think that the first answer can be useful to understand what you can and what you can't do in SQL Server and to know some methods to resolve your problem.